# Is there a way to rebind/associate a designer file with its cs file?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

I have a project in Xamarin, and my .designer.cs file is no longer nested under its .cs file which is causing compilation errors. Is there a way of associating them again so that I can compile my project? See below picture (ListHeader vs ListTableView).

[image: Solution Hierarchy.]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Edit your project file and try this:

```
<Compile Include="ListHeader.cs" />
<Compile Include="ListHeader.designer.cs">
   <DependentUpon>ListHeader.cs</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
```

Both files should be flagged as `Build Action / Compile`.

Comment: thank you. that was just what i was l was looking for. I figured there would be a simple way to do it, but wasn't able to find it in the documentation.

Comment: np, I've had more than one drag/drop failure and done this :-/