# Visual Studio 2013 designer shows an empty form, but on runtime it´s ok

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012

I copied two forms (and the corresponding .designer files, of course) from a test project to the definitive location. Changed namespaces and the like.
The resulting app runs as expected; both forms are shown with all its controls and behavior. 
Later, I needed to work on one of the forms, to add some controls to it.
But the designer shows it as a virgin Form, default size included, no controls, etc. Nevertheless, both .designer.cs files have all the controls defined, initialized, some event handlers in place, etc
I closed and reopened the solution, at no avail. 
Could someone help? If to add some controls to one of the forms a would need to entirely recreate it, it´s crazy. 
TIA

Comment: How did you add these files to the project?  Is the designer.cs file shown as a sub-item of the form.cs file?

Comment: Add existing item, navigated to the test project folder and selecting them. No, the designer.cs is not showing as a subitem; it shows as a separate item.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34010675/is-there-a-way-to-rebind-associate-a-designer-file-with-its-cs-file

Comment: May be it would be better to copy the entire folder (project included) and then add an existing project?

Comment: Followed your link´s recipe and it works! Thank you!

Comment: I will put as an answer the tip Hans Passant gave me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34010675/is-there-a-way-to-rebind-associate-a-designer-file-with-its-cs-file